# Error with graph.edgelist

Tags: social-networking, igraph

Hello I've been trying to convert my dataframe to a graph object using igraph package.

```
g = as.matrix(votings[,1:2])
g = graph.edgelist(votings, directed = TRUE)
Error in graph.edgelist(votings) :    graph_from_edgelist expects a matrix with two columns
```

I've also tried drop = FALSE, as other posts suggested.

```
g = graph.edgelist(votings[,1:2, drop = FALSE))
Error in graph.edgelist(votings) :    graph_from_edgelist expects a matrix with two columns
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with my code? The first two columns of votings contain character strings (names).

Comment: Call `as.matrix` on your data frame. Btw. `igraph` has a `graph_from_data_frame` function as well.

Comment: @GaborCsardi thank you! graph_from_data_frame worked! I tried as.matrix as well but for some reason, it wouldn't work for as for others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried graph_from_data_frame and it worked as Gabor Casardi suggested. Thank you! But if you want to use graph.edgelist, this works.

```
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(votings[,1:2, drop = FALSE], directed = TRUE))
```